# Why does my MacBook Air produce so much noise

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My MacBook Air's fan is spinning rapidly even though there are hardly any programs running. This normally only occurs when I am using the MacBook at a high intensity. However, the fan stops only when the MacBook shuts down. However, when I turn it back on again, it starts spinning at maximum speed again. Why is this so and how can I solve this problem? I need to use my MacBook urgently without it producing any noise from the fans.

Update:
I have included some screenshots from Activity Monitor. However, I am not sure which of them are applicable at this point in time. Sorry.

Comment: open you activity monitor and provide a screen shot to see what it makes go hot.

Comment: Thanks. I have added screenshots from Activity Monitor as suggested.                                            It seems that my battery icon at the top of my MacBook Air Screen has disappeared. It might have something to do with the above problem. I am using a late 2013 MacBook Air.

Comment: You can get the battery icon back from `System Preferences > Energy Saver > Show battery status in menu bar`

Comment: Since Activity Monitor didn't show anything unusual, I have deleted the screenshots for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, the Activity monitor does no show anything unusual.

You are a candidate for the SMC reset. SMC (system management controller) is responsible for fan control, the battery charging ect..

Follow the instructions [here for how to](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).

Apple kb HT3964

Comment: Thanks! Resetting the SMC solved all problems previously stated.

Answer (score -1):

If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>POWER</kbd> at the left side of the keyboard, hold it for ten seconds,  then wait, it will totally fix it.
[image]